# Regular expressions using conditions

Tags: regex, conditional-statements, code-snippets, sublimetext

I know that I really need to read one of these books ([1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449319432), [2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124)) to learn regular expressions but in the meantime I have a small question for the people that already have the knowledge.
I want to write a snippet for sublime text which leaves the inner spaces for parentheses if I start typing but deletes everything inside the parentheses if I delete the selection.

Triggered:

```
( ${1:anything could be typed here} )
```

Typed:

```
( I_wrote_that )
```

Deleted:

```
()
```

I do not ask for someone to write it for me, but a clear explanation on conditional regular expressions would be much appreciated.
Thanks !

NB: I am referring to the conditional syntax in regular expressions.
NB2: Here is an example with a C/C++ printf.

Snippet:

```
printf( "${1:%s}\\n" ${1/([^%]|%%)*(%.)?.*/(?2:,:\);)/} $2 ${1/([^%]|%%)*(%.)?.*/(?2:\);))/}
```

Gives:

```
printf( "%s\n" ,  );
```

Or:

```
printf( "\n" );
```

Comment: "conditional regular expressions", are you referring to the conditional syntax in some regex flavors `(?(condition)yes-pattern|no-pattern)`, or are you talking about something specific in sublime text?

Comment: I am referring to the conditional syntax in regular expressions.

Comment: What's the input, the condition and the expected output. It's unclear to me.

Comment: Anything could be typed inside the parentheses. But if the content is deleted, we also remove the inner padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Qtax already showed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080216/regular-expressions-using-conditions#comment26461541_18080216) you can use conditionals in regexp in such way:

`(?(condition)then|else)`

or

`(?(?=pattern)then|else)`

Regular Expressions are way to find patterns and similarities in input, but not a logic (otherwise I guess, it would be Logical Expressions too). If your program desires to put some logic into the regexp clause it's possibly first bells of a design flaw.

**UPDATE+**

Also, I don't understand

> Anything could be typed inside the parentheses. But if the content is deleted, we also remove the inner padding. – *Athanase*

Are you talking about dynamic regexp? It looks like you need some event-driven regexp or command line which will analyze your regexp while you're typing.

Also possible you're talking about `Sublime Text` features, but not about pure regexp (which also could have some deviations depend on implementation).

Comment: That is true, here is a sublime text example for a printf in C/C++: `printf( "${1:%s}\\n" ${1/([^%]|%%)*(%.)?.*/(?2:,:\);)/} $2 ${1/([^%]|%%)*(%.)?.*/(?2:\);))/}` , knowing that ${1:%s} places the selection on `%s` when the snippet is triggered.